# Convert free text date value to date data type leads to future year in converted date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am facing problem with conversion of freetext `DOB` (Date of Birth) value to valid date data type. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Following is the example.

When free text date value `01/28/48` is being converted through convert function of SQL then it is showing `2048` as year instead of `1948` which is future year and it is not possible in this date of birth column.

Can anyone help me to come out from this issue?

Following is the screenshot I have attached for your quick reference.

[image]

Comment: What about 01/28/10 - how would you know whether that should be treated as 1910 or 2010?

Comment: Apology for lack of information. This free text field is Date of Birth. if we will consider your date "01/28/10" and keep date of birth year as 1910. it would be rare case. but here we just concern about future date. it means i do not want future date. i want converted date which is less than today's date.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx maybe this could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a system-wide setting in SQL Server - the "two-digit year cutoff".

Check what it is for you like this:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
reconfigure

sp_configure 'two digit year cutoff'
```

In my case, I get a value of `2049` - any date with a year before that is considered a `20xx` year (e.g. `48` -> `2048`), dates with a year after that get interpreted as `19xx` (`70` -> `1970`).

So you can either change this setting for you, or then you'd need to write a custom T-SQL function to handle this case yourself (always converting dates to `19xx` dates - regardless of the system-cutoff date)

See more about this topic [in this blog post on how to set the two-digit year cutoff](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLDateTimeCutOff.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [CAST and CONVERT documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

> By default, SQL Server interprets two-digit years based on a cutoff
>   year of 2049. That is, the two-digit year 49 is interpreted as 2049
>   and the two-digit year 50 is interpreted as 1950. Many client
>   applications, such as those based on Automation objects, use a cutoff
>   year of 2030. SQL Server provides the two digit year cutoff
>   configuration option that changes the cutoff year used by SQL Server
>   and allows for the consistent treatment of dates. We recommend
>   specifying four-digit years.

You can reconfigure this by doing:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE ;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'two digit year cutoff', 2030 ;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

See the following documentation for more information:

[**Configure the two digit year cutoff Server Configuration Option**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms191004.aspx)

---

Personally I **wouldn't** reconfigure the server. Either ensure your data has 4 digit years, or if you *really* need them to be 2 digit, as these are always date of birth, remove 100 years if the Date is in the future:

```
DECLARE @dob DATE
SET @dob = CONVERT(DATE, '01/28/48')
IF @dob > GETDATE()
BEGIN
   SET @dob = DATEADD(yy, -100, @dob)
END
```